# Can we do conditional formatting in Power BI using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a KPI which I need to conditional format based on a dynamic condition.
Example:
KPI : A

```
if A > Average of A in that cluster(A column present in the table) then the cell should be RED
if A lies between some values then the cell should be AMBER
if A lies below some value then the cell should be GREEN
```

I was doing conditional formatting by RULES prior to this but I cant seem to find an option there which can dynamically calculate the Average cluster total or Average country total and format the cells with colours.
Even if I make this DAX expression how do I put it in the table?
Also, is it even possible by DAX?

Comment: What's wrong with using DAX measures/columns for [field based conditional formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting#format-background-or-font-color)?

Comment: my value is dynamic , the value through which the colours will change. I cant hard code the minimum or maximum value. my maximum value is the average of a particular column which will change each month.

Comment: Yes, and you can calculate this average with DAX and the "background color" measure will look at it and decide what background should be used. E.g. see [this](https://radacad.com/dax-and-conditional-formatting-better-together-find-the-biggest-and-smallest-numbers-in-the-column).